# End is not working in print() function in loops

Tags: python, set

I am trying the following code to execute which is giving me nothing in output. And when I remove end from print then it gives me the output but every element of the set is printing on new line. To get rid of this I am using end in print but its not working. PLEASE HELP!!

```
myset={'Haider','Wali','Aamir'}
for x in myset:
    print(x,end='')
```

Comment: It works well for me. What is your desired output of the code?

Comment: can you paste your expected output?

Comment: @Park My desired output is like I want to print the each element of the set on single line.

Comment: Add parameter `flush=True`

Comment: @LeiYang My expected output is:  Haider Wali Aamir

Comment: Where are you running the code?

Comment: @DevangSanghani I am running the code on Programiz Online Interpreter

Comment: @HaiderAli: As mentioned above by Mark , add `flush=True` after the `end=' '`. Or use repl.it It works as expected.

Comment: @DevangSanghani But what is this flush parameter and how it works? I am not getting what the Google is trying to say about flush parameter.. Hehehehe

Answer (score 1):

As a code is not clearly shown and an image cannot be attached on a comment, I write this answer, as follows:

```py
myset={'Haider', 'Wali', 'Aamir'}
for x in myset:
    print(x, end='')
#AamirHaiderWali -> output

print()

for x in myset:
    print(x, end=' ') # one space inside the single quotation marks
#Aamir Haider Wali -> output on single line as what you desired.
```

Following is an image of the result of the code.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!! Which IDE did you use? Because the same code is not working for me....

Comment: I ran the code on Python IDLE, PyCharm. I found that the code does not work on online Python executor (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/). Then you can use `flush=True' in print() such as `print(x, end=' ', flush=True`)` for all print functions.

Comment: @HaiderAli Did you solve the problem? Hope my answer was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a space in the end parameter. Try print(x, end=' ')

Comment: Usually Python appends a new line at the end of the sting by default. To override this we add an empty string at the end.

Comment: Its not working. I tried by putting the space in end parameter but it's still not working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).